# How to get SQLite values onClick recyclerview to show details in another activity

Tags: android, sqlite, onclick, android-recyclerview

I am new to Android and building a simple notes application to get started. I managed to implement recyclerview using [this](https://github.com/nikhilpanju/RecyclerViewEnhanced) library.

The recyclerview is the list of notes where I show the title and a short description. When the user clicks a row in the list, it opens up another activity and show the content of the note.

In order to do this, I need to get the id (the primary key in the SQLite DB) and pass to the details activity using `intent.putExtra`.

I have this method in the `onCreate` of the activity to handle recyclerview click events.

```
onTouchListener = new RecyclerTouchListener(this, mRecyclerView);
        onTouchListener
                    .setClickable(new RecyclerTouchListener.OnRowClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRowClicked(int position) {
                        // ToastUtil.makeToast(getApplicationContext(), "Row Position " + (position + 1) + " clicked!");
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotesDetailActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
```

In this method, I could get only the position of the row in the list. I need to get the id so I can pass to another activity where I can show the note content. Currently I am just showing the position in Toast when the user click a row in the list.

**ViewHolder**

```
@Override
    public MainViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notes_recycler, parent, false);
        return new MainViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MainViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bindData(modelList.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return modelList.size();
    }

    class MainViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {

        TextView mainText, subText;

        public MainViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mainText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mainText);
            subText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subText);
        }

        public void bindData(RowModel rowModel) {
            mainText.setText(rowModel.getMainText());
            subText.setText(rowModel.getSubText());

        }
    }
}
```

getData() to get the data from the notes table.

```
 private List<RowModel> getData() {
        List<RowModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor cursor = db.getAllNotes();
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            do {
                list.add(new RowModel(cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getInt(0)));
                // return list;
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        } else {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            String text = "No Data";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();

        }
        return list;
    }
```

If you need further information please let me know. It would be of great help if someone can help me solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if you are able to pass the ID using the intent then in onstart() of the details Activity call this method and pro

```
     private void makeDataRequest() {

            String mSelectionClause = YOUR_DATABASE_TABLE._ID + " =?";
            String[] mSelectionArgs = {String.valueOf(your_ID)};

        cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(Contract.CONTENT_URI,null,mSelectionClause,mSelectionArgs ,null);
        if (cursor==null){
            //some error, row is null or empty, handle it here
        }
        else {
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {

               //take a model class and store values in it or use it directly
                Model model;
                modelList.clear();
                while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
                    model = new Model();
                    model.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(YOUR_DATABASE_TABLE.CTITLE)));
                    model.setDesc(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(YOUR_DATABASE_TABLE.CDESCRIPTION)));
                    model.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(YOUR_DATABASE_TABLE._ID)));
                    cursor.moveToNext();
                    modelList.add(model);
                }

            }
            else {
                //some error handle it here
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I just want to access the id of the clicked row in the onRowClicked method. Now I can only get the position and show that as toast. It would be helpful if you can help me get the id(the primary key in SQLite) of the row to send it to another activity to fetch the details from SQLite using the id.

Comment: then in your onClick() just do something like :
 onRowClicked(int position) {
String rowId =  rowModelList.getID(position);
//start here intent}

Comment: i mean you have to store the data from sqlite into some arraylist then on click of the row get the position of row and get value from arraylist with position you get.